# Worklight console shows welcome: Hello, null

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-console

I have installed Worklight/MobileFirst Server step by step with IBM instruction.
After installation I have a problem, because appliaction shows error: 
*Server error. Contact the server administrator.*

In the top-right corner it shows welcome: *Hello, null.* I think that this null is the problem, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide the messages.log and server.log of your server. It'll also be nice if you'll mention which version of Worklight you're using... and on which application server you've deployed it to.

Comment: Waiting to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

If you get null as the username, then this more than likely due to incorrect installation. Something in your server.xml is not correctly set-up.

Since you do not supply any further required information as mentioned in the comments (namely the messages.log and the server.xml files), the only course of action is to request you to re-do the installation procedures to-the-letters as describe in the following user documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_installation.html